# Batch Ruby Sass Watch String

Tags: css, ruby, directory, sass, watch

I would like to run Ruby/Sass from the directory root I have my all projects saved using a batch file.

Ruby version: 1.9.3
Sass version: 3.2.7

For instance:

D:\all-projects

I would like run SASS.bat from the root folder and it should automatically execute the watch function watch for sass on all projects, like this:

```
sass --watch D:\all-projects/sass:public/stylesheets
```

At the moment I got this:

```
@echo off
cmd.exe /E:ON /K C:\Ruby193\bin\setrbvars.bat

sass --watch D:\all-projects/sass:public/stylesheets
```

This starts only ruby in the root directory but **does not run the watch function for Sass**.

I'm looking for this solution because it would make the usage of Sass a lot easier and effective.

At the moment you have to run RUBY -> look up for the directory -> run sass --watch ...

How can I do this? What should I change in order to make this work?

I welcome all hints and helps.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Out of curiosity are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: No, Adobe Dreamweaver and more than that Komodo Edit 8.

Comment: Does the batch file stay open after you run it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it works:

```
@echo off
cmd.exe /E:ON /K C:\Ruby193\bin\setrbvars.bat
START /B sass --watch D:\all-projects\sass:public\stylesheets
PAUSE
```

I have created batch files for SASS in the past and did something similar to this. However I never had to run Ruby in the BATCH file. So I am sort of curious as to why you need to start ruby.

**EDIT: (basic example)**

*This is all you should need to create a basic batch file with SASS.*

-Create a Batch file called **test.bat** with the following code and save to your desktop.

```
@echo off 
sass --watch file.scss
PAUSE
```

-Create a blank .scss file called **test.scss** and save to your desktop.
 -Now run your batch file and it should create **file.css** and say...

```
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
overwrite file.css
```

Comment: Any errors or messages? Try putting the batch file in the same directory as the sass files change the path and see if it works. It might be an issue with the path.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work as excepted!

On exit I get an error message: **Windows cannot find 'sass'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.**

The Sass files are in *.scss

The reason I said to run Ruby in the batch file is because you need to process Sass with it, isn't it?

Comment: My guess is your sass or ruby install isn't configured right. You shouldn't have to run ruby it should just automatically run. You can check to see if SASS is installed by running sass --version in the command prompt. If you don't get back a version then something isn't right.

Comment: You can also check ruby by doing the same thing. ruby --version

Comment: Ruby version: 1.9.3
Sass version: 3.2.7

Comment: Okay, so if you do sass --watch your/path from the command line do you still get that error? Or just run the command sass --watch and see if you can reproduce that error.

Comment: On click of the batch file there is no **"Sass is watching your changes. Press CTRL+C to stop."** Visible is only the ruby version and the path to the root directory. I still have to start the watching manually.

Comment: I added instructions in my answer as to how to create the most basic batch file using SASS. Give that a try and see if it works. If that works then double check your paths. If that doesn't work then double check your Ruby / SASS environment configuration.

Comment: Hi Kris,

thanks for your support but the same issue is persistent.
I have followed your instructions step by step and still no luck :(

Comment: How much rep do you need? I don't remember.

Comment: 15 rep is required from me?

Comment: Hi,
the way I installed sass is via ruby 1.9.3.
First I've installed ruby then started ruby command propmt and then used gem install sass.

Comment: Thanks! This works just fine for me. Ruby can be ignored for the setup. I created a cmd file in the same folder as my css. The contents are: sass --watch styles.scss:styles.css
PAUSE